# Creating templates in emacs

Tags: org-agenda, org-capture, template

I need to create a weekly agenda that has the same outline.  I currently have a Word template file that I use, but would like to convert it to emacs.  I want the emacs "template" to pre-fill the common text and present me with fields for updating the information that changes week to week.

I looked into [Forms Mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/forms.html), but that looks more database oriented.  I read some information about using [Skeleton Mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SkeletonMode), but I would like to have fillable fields that I could quickly enter throughout the skeleton text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at [Agenda Views](http://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-Views.html), [Org-Mode Capture Templates](http://orgmode.org/manual/Capture-templates.html#Capture-templates) and / or [YASnippet](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet).

With `Org-Mode` you can set up capture templates for various tasks and for different target locations, and consolidate all that information in `Agenda Views`. Morever you can quickly store notes with little interruption to your workflow.

There's a [wealth of information](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-gtd-etc.html) for implementing *David Allen's* [GTD](http://gettingthingsdone.com/) - *Getting Things Done* stratergies within an Emacs environment.

**YASnippet** *is a template system for Emacs that allows you to type an abbreviation and quickly expand it into function templates*

Combining the powerful tools of `Org-Mode` together with `YASnippet` should allow you to realise the desired weekly templated agendas.

Comment: Just wanted to bring some light to my package `yankpad`, which lets you write and organize snippets in an `org-mode`-file. It uses YASnippet internally if it is installed. https://github.com/Kungsgeten/yankpad

Comment: Org-Mode and YASnipper definitely meets my needs.  I will also add widgets which I stumbled on over the weekend.